# SQL Query slows down if I include a column in GROUP BY causes

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have following query and it execute just fine.
It takes less than 1 sec to get results.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Items.ImageID AS ImgID, Items.AddDate, MIN(ra1.DescPriority) AS Pri
FROM            Items 
INNER JOIN      Attribs AS ra0 ON Items.ImageID = ra0.ImageID 
INNER JOIN      Attribs AS ra1 ON ra0.ImageID = ra1.ImageID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN v_priceOrder ON Items.ImageID = v_priceOrder.ImageID
WHERE        (Items.deleted NOT IN (1, 2)) 
GROUP BY Items.ImageID, Items.AddDate
ORDER BY pri, Items.AddDate DESC
```

However, if I try to add a column from PriceOrder View in select lists it takes 10 seconds to get results.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Items.ImageID AS ImgID, Items.AddDate, MIN(ra1.DescPriority) AS Pri,
    v_priceOrder.PriceOrder
FROM            Items 
INNER JOIN      Attribs AS ra0 ON Items.ImageID = ra0.ImageID 
INNER JOIN      Attribs AS ra1 ON ra0.ImageID = ra1.ImageID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN v_priceOrder ON Items.ImageID = v_priceOrder.ImageID
WHERE        (Items.deleted NOT IN (1, 2)) 
GROUP BY Items.ImageID, Items.AddDate, v_priceOrder.PriceOrder
ORDER BY v_priceOrder.PriceOrder, pri, Items.AddDate DESC
```

Is there a way to improve this query?
In the Execution plan I only see 0 or 1% cost.
I'm using MS SQL Server 2008 R2.

**UPDATE:**
My View had a issue. It takes 8 seconds to run...
Here is the Query.

```
SELECT     dbo.Items.ImageID, 
                          CASE WHEN dbo.Items.SubcategoryID2 = 'STO' THEN dbo.v_DisplayStockPrice.DisplayPrice WHEN dbo.Items.SubcategoryID2 = 'ORD' THEN dbo.v_FinalPriceFactor.[14kyFactorOrder]
                          WHEN dbo.Items.SubcategoryID2 IS NULL THEN dbo.v_FinalPriceFactor.[14kyCustomLow] END AS PriceOrder
FROM       dbo.v_FinalPriceFactor RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                          dbo.Items ON dbo.v_FinalPriceFactor.ImageID = dbo.Items.ImageID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                          dbo.v_DisplayStockPrice ON dbo.Items.ImageID = dbo.v_DisplayStockPrice.ImageID
WHERE     (dbo.Items.deleted NOT IN (1, 2))
```

Comment: Why do you need DISTINCT and GROUP BY? Please help us help you. Show the table structure, some sample data, and desired results. And if you're going to talk about an execution plan, make sure it's an actual, and provide it for us! http://dba.blogoverflow.com/2012/06/help-us-help-you/

Comment: ah, I see... I don't need DISTINCT. I've been modifying syntacx and end up using without knowing what it is. I just found my issue. My View (v_priceOrder) has some issue.

Comment: Why do you join twice the `Attribs` table?

Answer (score 1):

I had cross join in my Views causing unnecessary loops...